# Explode in jquery with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I've got a jquery script, which creates a h3 tag and print a variable called result.tbUrl to it. I'd like to explode the variable at "`::`" and use the 2nd piece.

This is my method.

```
var link = document.createElement('h3');
link.innerHTML = <?php $link = "result.tbUrl"; $linkpiece = explode("::", $link); echo $pieces[1]; ?>;
```

Could you tell me please where did i make a mistake?

Comment: FYI, there is no jquery on your snippet, better to tag it as javascript and edit question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is, you're echoing `$pieces[1]`, but exploding your string into `$linkpiece` which is a different variable.

However, you have a more serious problem: You're setting `$link` to the string "result.tbUrl".  The string doesn't contain the delimiter '::', so exploding it has no effect and `$linkpiece` will be set to `array(0 => 'result.tbUrl')`.  The line `echo $linkpiece[1]` will fail regardless, as there is nothing at index 1.

If `result.tbUrl` is a JavaScript variable, you cannot mix it with server-side PHP this way.  You'll have to explode the variable client-side, in JavaScript:

```
var parts = result.tbUrl.split('::');
link.innerHTML = parts[1];
```

Comment: also the exploded array is called $linkpiece, not $pieces